# app.js:55 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')

Tags: javascript, arrays, jquery-selectors, undefined, nodelist

i have checked the node list before adding the 'fetchValues' function to make sure that it have a value , but when i add the function , this error shows up:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')

i dont understand why the code runs with no issues and the opposet when i add the function ?

```
const fetchValues = (attrs, ...nodeLists) => {
    let elemsAttrCount = nodeLists.length;
    let elemsDataCount = nodeLists[0].length;
    let tempDataArr = [];

    //first loop deals with the no of repeaters value
    for(let i = 0; i<elemsDataCount; i++ ){
        let dataObj = {}; // creating an empty obj to fill the data
        //second loop feletej th0eajh<eelemeaters value or attributes
        for (let j = 0; j < elemsAttrCount; i++ ) {
            // setting the key name for the obj and fill it with data
            dataObj ['${attrs[j]}'] = nodeLists[j][i].value;
        }
        tempDataArr.push(dataObj);
    }
    return tempDataArr;
}
```

and here is the code when a checked it , before and after the function :

```
// before
    let acheivementsTitleElem = document.querySelectorAll('.acheiv-title'),
    acheivementsDescriptionElem = document.querySelectorAll('.acheiv-description');
    console.log(acheivementsTitleElem,acheivementsDescriptionElem);
```

```
// after
    let acheivementsTitleElem = document.querySelectorAll('.acheiv-title'),
    acheivementsDescriptionElem = document.querySelectorAll('.acheiv-description');
    console.log(fetchValues(['acheiv-title','acheiv-description'],acheivementsTitleElem,acheivementsDescriptionElem));
```

i tried to understand it but i didn't find any logic reason of not finding the value of the node list

Comment: Not related to the error, but `['${attrs[j]}']` should be `[attrs[j]]`

Comment: The error implies that the elements of `nodeLists` aren't all the same length. You'll get that error if any of them are shorter than `nodeLists[0]`.

Comment: What does `console.log(acheivementsTitleElem.length, acheivementsDescriptionElem.length)` show?

Comment: It shows 1 1 , the DevTools shows that the error is in : "nodeList[ j ][ i ].value " Wich is exactly in "value"

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: This means that for at least one index combination `i` and `j` Your `nodelists[i][j]`  is undefined. This can have multiple reasons. The most probable one being, that the differnt inner arrays in your `nodelists` have different lengths (ie `nodelists[0]` is probably longer than for instance `nodelists[1]`